# If directive should not be loaded by some conditional?

Tags: dom, angularjs-directive, loaded

I have one directive but sometimes I dont want it to be loaded.

```
<div class="col-sm-12 panel panel-default" ng-if="DisplayName=='Automatic'">
    <div automatic-dir opt='opt'></div>
</div>
```

I tried `ng-if`, `ng-show` Ok it was not showed, but both of them my directive loaded.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change your DOM structure than one of the possible way is like [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/TjRgVJ?p=preview) or in one of the simplest way like

```
<ul ng-controller="ListViewCtrl" >
   <li ng-repeat="item in items">
      <span>{{item.name}}</span>
      <div automatic-dir opt='opt' ng-if="item.hasMenu"></div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

If you are driving the automatic-dir of a class, you should be able to do this:

```
<ul ng-controller="ListViewCtrl" >
   <li ng-class="{'hasmenu': item.hasMenu}" ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.name}} </li>
</ul>
```

Could you please tell specifically what exact problem you are facing to get it done with ng-if ? A plunker would be an added advantage to get it resolved quickly.

You can resolve this by either building the directive with default and/or conditional behaviour do desired things by putting logic in link or controller of the directive definition or you can put condition in previous DOM element with [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) of directive. Please note that the later way is not amongst the best practices of angular.